# why is the variable undefined

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')
```

**For example, the user enters the path of the chrome.exe but it says it is undefined, maybe because it is in the root.mainloop, I have tried to put it outside of the mainloop but same result**

```
def exeNew():
        Path = text0.get(1.0, "end-1c")


text0 = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=30)
text0.place(x=400, y=500)

printButton = tk.Button(root, text="ADD", command=exeNew)
printButton.place(x=460, y=640)
```

**Then here os.startfile should open chrome.exe**

```
os.startfile(Path)

root.mainloop()
```

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awKrw.png)

Comment: Hi Giannis, can you please provide the error you're encountering? As in the full stacktrace Python gave when you tried to run the program?

Comment: I edited in just now.

Comment: @GiannisTsakas **don't post images of text. Post text as *formatted text in the question itself***

Comment: In any case, it isn't clear exactly what your code is doing (please **always** provide a [mcve]) but it loopks like you expect `exeNew` to create a `Path` variable that is available globally. It doesn't. It creates a local variable

Comment: Why don't you put the line `os.startfile(Path)` inside `exeNew()`?

Comment: because i have done a minimal reproducible example here and thats not what i want

Comment: When `os.startfile(Path)` is executed, `Path` is not created yet even though you put `global Path` inside `exeNew()` because `exeNew()` has not been executed.  Putting `os.startfile(Path)` inside `exeNew()` is what you want.  Also using `Entry` instead of `Text` is better if you just want to input a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You variable Path is only defined inside the function. You cannot access to it from outside the function.

It same as

```py
def declare_variable():
    x = 5
print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

One solution would be to declare Path before creating the button

Here an example

```py
x = 0
def declare_variable():
        global x
        x = 5
```

I test it

```py
x = 0
def declare_variable():
        global x
        x = 5

print(f"Before calling function : {x}")
declare_variable()
print(f"After calling function : {x}")
```

Here the output that i got

```bash
 python3 test4.py
Before calling function : 0
After calling function : 5
```

Comment: declaring Path before the button won't fix the issue alone, as the `Path` in exeNew will still be local to the function.

Comment: If you add global inside the function it will work

Comment: Still doesnt work , i think the problem is that we are not "calling" the function in the normal way. We call it by `command=exeNew`

Comment: @Giannis Tsakas.  Path = filename  os.startfile(Path)

Comment: @toyotaSupra AGAIN... have done it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

the function exeNew is setting a local variable `Path` which then no longer exists after exiting the scope of exeNew.

In exeNew, insert the line `global Path` before setting Path.

you may want to consider explicitly setting Path to None at the start of the program and only call os.startfile if Path is not None.

Comment: I did that and it still doesnt work , i think it has something to do with me calling the function in the `printButton` etc etc `command=exeNew` instead of calling it on its own?

Comment: thinking about this a bit more, ( i haven't done tkinter in a while), you probably want to use Entry instead of Text, and then a StringVar to get the value from the Entry. you pass the StringVar to the Entry field via the textvariable keyword parameter.  I'll try to type up an example later. currently on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think declaring the variable `Path` as global will be needed.

In more detail global variables,are variables that are accessible globally, or everywhere throughout the program. Once declared, they remain in memory throughout the runtime of the program. This means that they can be changed by any function at any point and may affect the program as a whole.

Comment: even if i declare it as a global it still comes up as undefined

Comment: `def exeNew():
    global Path
    Path = text0.get(1.0, "end-1c")`

Comment: You can also try Entry and a Button to take what is passed inside.